# How to run a memory consuming application using windows scheduler?

Tags: console, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, scheduling, memory-consumption

I have a console application which consumes at most 5Gb RAM while running. I want to initiate this application using windows scheduler. The problem is windows scheduler closes the application when it reaches 400-500mb of RAM usage. I have also changed the priority of the app from 7 to 0 in the task's XML configuration but seen no improvement.
I have received the following error message while trying to run the application.
any help?
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmBIp.jpg)